# Is it possible to combine different paths into a view or an object?

Tags: java, android

I created a drawing using different paths, but how can I move the entire drawing? How can I selected and move it around? Here is the main part of my onDraw method:

```
Path theSymbol = new Path();

theSymbol.moveTo(0.0F, 0.0F);
theSymbol.lineTo(0.0F, 50.0F);
theSymbol.lineTo(16.666666F, 58.333332F);
theSymbol.lineTo(-16.666666F, 75.0F);
theSymbol.lineTo(16.666666F, 91.666664F);
theSymbol.lineTo(-16.666666F, 108.33333F);
theSymbol.lineTo(16.666666F, 124.99999F);
theSymbol.lineTo(-16.666666F, 141.66666F);
theSymbol.lineTo(0.0F, 150.0F);
theSymbol.lineTo(0.0F, 200.0F);
theSymbol.offset(100.0F, 20.0F);

canvas.drawPath(theSymbol, paint);
```

That's how I draw a resistor to the screen (It works).  Now I want some way of making all those paths be an object, something that I can select and move.

I have been looking at some projects like [Sriracha](http://code.google.com/p/sriracha), but I can't find how they are doing their element drawings.

I have also searched countless times, but all I get is "moving something on a path". Maibe I am searching for the wrong thing or this is not the way to do this kind of things.

I wold really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this drawing code into the `onDraw()` method of a custom `View` subclass.  Then you can place your drawings around the screen however you like using layouts, animations, and other transformations just like any other view in the framework.  Something like:

```
public class ResistorView extends View {
    private Path mSymbol;
    private Paint mPaint;

    //...Override Constructors...
    public ResistorView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ResistorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mSymbol = new Path();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        //...Your code here to set up the path,
        //...allocate objects here, never in the drawing code.
    }

    //...Override onMeasure()...
    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        //Use this method to tell Android how big your view is
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    //...Override onDraw()...
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawPath(mSymbol, mPaint);
    }        

}
```

For more information about creating custom views, [check out the SDK docs](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html).

HTH

Comment: OMG I am going to try this now! THANK YOU so much!

Comment: Ok now that I have that class, from where should I call it or something every time I want to create/draw a resistor to the screen? I have 3 classes: DefaultActivity.java MyView.java (which extends SurfaceView) and ResistorView.java how can I implement the ResistorView class?